# Alternative formulation for MIS problem

Tags: graph-theory, linear-programming

The **Maximum Independent Set (MIS)** problem in graph theory consists on finding the largest independent set in a graph, where an independent set is a set of vertices such that no two vertices are adjacent.

If we suppose that the graph has n vertices, a solution can be interpreted as $\{0,1\}^{n}$ vector:

$$
X=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)
$$

where $$x_i=
\left\{
\begin{array}{ l }
1\quad if\quad v_i\in S\\
0\quad if\quad v_i\notin S
\end{array}
\right.
$$

In this way, I know the optimization problem can be formulated as

$$
max \quad  \sum_{i=1}^nx_i 
$$
$$
s.a. \quad \sum_{(v_i,v_j)\in E}x_ix_j=0 .
$$

However, I am asked to give an alternative formulation using a different mathematic object to represent the solution but I am stuck.

Any advice on how I can proceed?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You used the linear-programming tag, so note that you can rewrite your quadratic constraint as linear constraints $x_i + x_j \le 1$.

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic vector $x\in\{0,1\}^n$ is the standard approach to represent the node subset for optimization.  You can also rewrite each such vector as a bit string of length $n$ or the corresponding integer.  For example, for $n=5$, the subset $\{2,4,5\}$ corresponds to characteristic vector $(0,1,0,1,1)$ and bit string $01011$, and integer $2^0+2^1+2^4=19$.